# Alignat: column not flushing right to the margin

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment, alignment, alignat

I am trying to use `alignat*` to have flushed-right comments on equations. The comments are correctly aligned, but I can't find a way to ensure they are flushing to the document's margins. Either the comments don't go all the way right:

[image: comments not right enough]

or the comments bleed into the margin:

[image: comments too far right]

It seems like the comment placement is determined by the longest equation length and the longest comment length. However, that's not necessary, because some long equations have short comments that won't run into them. I would like it to be something like this:

[image: correct placement]

The LaTeX code is given. I have to use the `report` document class. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% For binomial coefficients that look better i.e. \mbinom
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{bbm}

\begin{document}
% First example: comments aren't far enough right
{\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&= \sum_{\substack{B \le \beta \\ |B| < \ell}} (-1)^{|B|} \mbinom{\beta}{B} f_{B} \sum_{\substack{P \le A \\ |P| = |B|}} \mbinom{A}{P} g(P + B) \Psi_{A - P} &\small\text{[induction hypothesis]} \\
&=  \sum_{P \le A } \sum_{B \le \beta}  \mathbbm{1}_{|P| = |B|}  \mathbbm{1}_{|B| < \ell} \thinspace (-1)^{|B|} \mbinom{A}{P} \mbinom{\beta}{B} \Psi_{A - P} &\small\text{[Thm.~1]} \\ \\
&= \sum_{P \le A } \sum_{B \le \beta}  \mathbbm{1}_{|P| = |B|}  \mathbbm{1}_{|P| < \ell} \thinspace (-1)^{|P|} \mbinom{A}{P} \mbinom{\beta}{B} \Psi_{A - P} &\small\text{[since $|P| = |B|$]} 
\end{alignat*}}

\bigskip
\bigskip

% Second example: comments bleed into the margin
{\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&= \sum_{\substack{B \le \beta \\ |B| < \ell}} (-1)^{|B|} \mbinom{\beta}{B} H_{\beta - B} \sum_{\substack{P \le A \\ |P| = |B|}} \mbinom{A}{P} \langle H_{P}, H_{B} \rangle H_{A - P} &\small\text{[induction hypothesis]} \\
&=  \sum_{P \le A } \sum_{B \le \beta}  \mathbbm{1}_{|P| = |B|}  \mathbbm{1}_{|B| < \ell} \thinspace (-1)^{|B|} \mbinom{A}{P} \mbinom{\beta}{B}  \langle H_{P}, H_{B} \rangle \Psi_{A - P} \Psi_{\beta - B} &\small\text{[Thm.~2]} \\ 
&\vdots \\
&=  \sum_{\substack{P \le A  \\ |P| < |A| = \ell} }  \thinspace (-1)^{|P|} \mbinom{A}{P} H_{A - P} \thinspace \partial^{P} H_{\beta} &\small\text{[induc.~on $\partial^{P}\Psi_{\beta}$ for $|P| < \ell$]} \\
&= \mathcal{S}_2.
\end{alignat*}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ‘amsmath’ defines ‘\tag*{label}’, which typeset custom label at a place where equation number would be. It is usually at the right margin. The starred version causes the label to be typeset literally.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Your hypothesis that the total width of the display block is caused by the length of the longest left-hand plus the longest right-hand component is correct.  "Shortening" the over-long left-hand component of the longest line by using `\mathrlap` (requires `mathtools`) plus setting the right-hand elements using `\tag*` as already suggested should give the result you're looking for.  (I won't say this is the best solution, but I'm not in a position to experiment at the moment.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you use an `align*` environment and place the comments in `\tag*` "wrappers"; `\tag*` is a macro provided by the `amsmath` package. User @Celdor has already made this suggestion in a comment.

To limit the extent to which the presence of the comments push the main math material to the left, I suggest "hiding" the `[induction` substring in an `\llap` directive, effectively making it disappear from the width calculations that are performed in the background.

To provide a visual clue that the `\mathbbm{1}_{...}` elements -- indicator functions, right? -- are "math operators" (in the same way that `\ln` and `\sin` are math operators), the code below creates a macro named `\one` that's given math-operator status.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % omit 'showframe' option in real doc.
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathclap macro; load amsmath autom.
\usepackage{amssymb,bbm}
\newcommand\one[1]{\mathop{\mathbbm{1}^{}_{#1}}} % indicator function
\usepackage{nccmath} % For \mbinom macro
%%\usepackage{float} % not needed

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&= \sum_{\substack{B \le \beta \\ |B| < \ell}} 
   (-1)^{|B|} \mbinom{\beta}{B} f_{B} 
   \sum_{\substack{P \le A \\ \mathclap{|P| = |B|}}} 
   \mbinom{A}{P} g(P + B) \Psi_{\!A - P} 
   \tag*{\llap{[induction} hypothesis]} \\
&= \sum_{P \le A } \sum_{B \le \beta}  
   \one{|P| = |B|} \one{|B| < \ell} \,
   (-1)^{|B|} \mbinom{A}{P} \mbinom{\beta}{B} \Psi_{\!A - P} 
   \tag*{[Thm.\ 1]} \\
&= \sum_{P \le A } \sum_{B \le \beta}  
   \one{|P| = |B|} \one{|P| < \ell} \,
   (-1)^{|P|} \mbinom{A}{P} \mbinom{\beta}{B} \Psi_{\!A - P} 
   \tag*{[since $|P| = |B|$\,]} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own macro `\commentedmath` with two parameters: `math` and `comment` based on TeX primitive:

```
\hbox to\hsize {$math$ \hss comment}
```

For example, like this:

```
\def\commentedmath#1#2{\par
   \smallskip
   \hbox to\hsize{$\displaystyle{}#1$\hss[#2]}
   \smallskip
}

\commentedmath
{ = \sum_{\substack{B\le\beta \\ |B|<\ell}} (-1)^{|B|} 
        \mbinom{\beta}{B} f_{B} 
    \sum_{\substack{P\le A \\ |P|=|B|}} 
        \mbinom{A}{P} g(P + B) \Psi_{A - P} }   {induction hypothesis}
\commentedmath
{ = \sum_{P\le A} \sum_{B\le\beta} \mathbbm{1}_{|P|=|B|} \mathbbm{1}_{|B|<\ell} 
  \, (-1)^{|B|} \mbinom{A}{P} \mbinom{\beta}{B} 
  \Psi_{A-P} }                                  {Thm. 1}
\commentedmath
{ = \sum_{P\le A} \sum_{B\le\beta} \mathbbm{1}_{|P|=|B|} \mathbbm{1}_{|P|<\ell}
  \; (-1)^{|P|} \mbinom{A}{P} \mbinom{\beta}{B} 
  \Psi_{A-P} }                                  {since $|P|=|B|$}
```